# Follow links in a loop with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to learn the `rvest` package, but the documentation and the examples on the web are either very basic or very complex. I could not find how to use the `follow_link` function in a loop to browse some number of pages. Perhaps I did not understand its logic at all...

Here is a simplified example of my attempt:

```
library(rvest)

url <-
  "https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Q5&limit=500"

s <- html_session(url)

liste <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
  data <-
    s %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#mw-whatlinkshere-list li")

  result <- c(liste, data)

  s <- s %>% 
    follow_link(xpath = "//a[text()='next 500']/@href")

}
```

I've also tried to avoid the `jump_link`, like this : it's better, but I'm not sure is the best and fastest solution :

```
liste <- c()
while (!is.na(url)) {
  data <-
    url %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes("#mw-whatlinkshere-list li")


  liste <- c(liste, data)

  url <- url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node(xpath = "//a[text()='next 500']") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% 
    paste0("https://www.wikidata.org", .) 

  print(url)


}
```

Any advice is welcome and would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Special:WhatLinksHere/Q5&limit=500"
s   <- html_session(url)

liste <- list()
for (i in 1:2) {
        data <-
                s %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_nodes("#mw-whatlinkshere-list li")

        # There was a mistake here. You were overwriting your results
        liste <- c(liste, data) 

        # Here you have to pass a 'a' tag, not a 'href' value. Besides,
        # there is two 'next 500' tags. They are the same, but you have
        # to pick one.
        s <- s %>% 
            follow_link(xpath = "//a[text()='next 500'][1]") 
}
```

Comment: Okay ... It's my fault, I misread the (thin) documentation. Thank you very much ! (even a year later)